# Assignment rules don't run in test class

Tags: unit-test, assignment-rules

I am writing a test class for cases. I want to test certain things of course and want to rely on the actual behaviour. Therefore I would like assignment rules to run when inserting test cases. They are not however. I found this [article](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/running-case-assignment-rules-from-apex) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Any ideas?

Thanks / Niklas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding the seeAllData annotation to your test method

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
static void test_mockIfAtAllPossible(){
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion!

I have been spending the last hour reading raw logs and can see now that the assignment rules actually fires using the proposed way in the article linked to from above.

So all rule fires (assignment,workflow,auto-response,escalation), in fact I can see, from the logs that they return true in the right places.

In my code when I declare the case, like this:
Case case1 = new Case(...);
the rules fires before inserting the case.

Neither before or after this I can compare the values in my test class, i.e. the case values to be set by rules are always null.

Comment: are you selecting the case back out of the database once the rules have fired?  You have to refresh your object from the database after insert/update if any changes happen through workflow/trigger for it to reflect in your object.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

To sum up: the assignment rules actually ran, I just didn't see the result until I selected the case record after insert.